# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

Have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04, how to install and where to install it from

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a duplicate but you can find instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support)